# Using None in a Python if conditional

Tags: python, if-statement, nonetype

When I do:

```
if breadcrumb is not None:
    attrdict['breadcrumb'] = breadcrumb[0]
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The whole point of the conditional was to skip all this if the var is None, but that doesn't work. So it seems I can't use None in a conditional, and I have to do a try/except instead.
Is this correct? If so, why? If not, how do I make it work as expected?

Comment: Are you sure `attrdict` is not `None`?

Comment: Python 3.11 should make [this kind of error](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#enhanced-error-locations-in-tracebacks) easier to diagnose.

Comment: OP: (1) your question did not show the “top of the script” where you say attrdict was initialized, so the query in @Mitcell’s comment is understandable: (2) if attrdict is None, and you try to use square brackets on it, no key will be created and you may well get the error you are receiving, so again the query is understandable; (3) not sure there’s any evidence here supporting your hypothesis that others know less than you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with `attrdict`. Try `print(attrdict is None)`.

Comment: Same answer I gave Mitchell.